# SSRS REPORT ERROR "An item with the same key has already been added

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I am creating a report in SSRS and get the following error.

[image]

Comment: The error is due to multiple columns with the same name. You are SELECTing ALL FIELDS with * and adding a couple that are included. You would need to alias the DESC fields - though why do you need them twice anyways?

Comment: How should I go about fixing it. I do not need them twice.

Comment: If you need all the other columns, you can just remove the `ch_long_desc` and `ch_short_desc`. Though you should only SELECT the columns you need.

Comment: Remove '*' from your query and add only columns you want.

Comment: if you need the same column twice .. use the same one twice.. o.0